# AngularJS passing objects from main controllers to other controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angularjs and Ionic. I am currently building my first app and I want to know, is there any way I can inject expressions in the main controller and use them in all the other controllers.

So instead of typing $scope, $http, $Ionicpopup in every controller. I want to put that in my main controller and use them in all other controllers.

> var app=angular.module('app.controllers', []);

Can you tell me what this is called?

Comment: No unfortunately you have to inject them in every controller that requires those dependencies. That's just how angular works. As for your second question, that would be an angular module.

Comment: @hsiung, i see, can you tell me if there is a way I can make my own expression and use it in different controllers? Without having to initialize it in each controller

Comment: You can [inherit controllers](http://blog.mgechev.com/2013/12/18/inheritance-services-controllers-in-angularjs/) Most suggest using services and emitting events on the scope to communicate between controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We normally use service to communicate between controllers.

In the following sample example, we create **animalService**, and inject it to both controllers. We then use **$watch** to monitor the changes.

http://plnkr.co/edit/hfKuxJO2XZdB6MsK7Ief

```js
(function () {

    angular.module("root", [])
      .controller("leftAnimal", ["$scope", "animalService",
        function ($scope, animalService) {

            $scope.findNewAnimal = function () {
                var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * animalPool.length);
                $scope.animal = animalPool[randNum];
                console.log("Left Click Index: " + randNum);
                animalService.setAnimal(randNum);
            };

            $scope.$watch(function () {
                return animalService.getAnimal();
            }, function (value) {
                $scope.animal = animalPool[value];
            });
        }
      ])
      .controller("rightAnimal", ["$scope", "animalService",
        function ($scope, animalService) {

            $scope.findNewAnimal = function () {
                var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * animalPool.length);
                $scope.animal = animalPool[randNum];
                console.log("Right Click Index: " + randNum);
                animalService.setAnimal(randNum);
            };

            $scope.$watch(function () {
                return animalService.getAnimal();
            }, function (value) {
                $scope.animal = animalPool[value];
            });
        }
      ])
      .factory("animalService", [function () {
          var index = 0;
          function getAnimal() {
              return index;
          }
          function setAnimal(newIndex) {
              index = newIndex;
          }
          return {
              getAnimal: getAnimal,
              setAnimal: setAnimal,
          }
      }]);

    var animalPool = [{
        name: "Baby Quetzal",
        img: "http://i.imgur.com/CtnEDpM.jpg",
        baby: true
    }, {
        name: "Baby Otter",
        img: "http://i.imgur.com/1IShHRT.jpg",
        baby: true
    }, {
        name: "Baby Octopus",
        img: "http://i.imgur.com/kzarlKW.jpg",
        baby: true
    }];
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="root">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
     <div class="row">
        <div class="text-center">
            <h2>Pick an Animal</h2>
        </div>
        <div ng-controller="leftAnimal" class="col-md-6">
            <div class="animalImage">
                <img class="img-center" ng-src="{{animal.img}}"/>
            </div>
            <div class="animalName">{{animal.name}}</div>
            <div class="animalDescription">{{animal.description}}</div>
            <button type="button" ng-click="findNewAnimal()"
                    class="btn btn-info img-center">
                Change
            </button>
        </div>
        <div ng-controller="rightAnimal" class="col-md-6">
            <div class="animalImage">
                <img class="img-center" ng-src="{{animal.img}}" />
            </div>
            <div class="animalName">{{animal.name}}</div>
            <div class="animalDescription">{{animal.description}}</div>
            <button type="button" ng-click="findNewAnimal()"
                    class="btn btn-info img-center">
                Change
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I wanted. I really appreciate you pasting all the codes, it helped me understand better!

Answer (score 0):

In AngularJS you have to inject your dependencies into each controller. In that way, each controller only has exactly the dependencies that it needs instead of any extraneous ones.

The line

```
var app=angular.module('app.controllers', []);
```

is just how you tell AngularJS that you want to make a new module. Then to add things to the module you just make calls like

```
app.controller('controllerName', function() {/* your stuff here */});
app.filter('filterName', function() {/* your stuff here */});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have another question then, is there a way I can make my own expression and use it in different controllers? Without having to initialize it in each controller

Comment: Yeah, take a look at the new answer I just posted.

Answer (score 0):

To make your own expression and use it in other parts of your code try something like this:

```
var myApp=angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.value('clientId', 'a12345654321x'); // this sets a value
```

Then if you include `clientId` as a dependency anywhere it would be equal to `a12345654321x` wherever it was injected.

To use your value in other places just include it as a dependency

```
myApp.controller('mycontroller', ['clientId', function(clientId) {
    console.log(clientId);
}]);
```

For more complex behaviors you can get into other types of AngularJS providers like factories. Here's the docs for reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers